# Ionic 2: Error testing with Karma/Jasmine/TestBed

Tags: ionic2, karma-jasmine, testbed

I'm new with Ionic2 and I was following [this](https://www.joshmorony.com/introduction-to-testing-ionic-2-applications-with-testbed/) tutorial and a simple test like

```
describe('Dummy test', () => {

it('should do nothing', () => {

    expect(true).toBeTruthy();
    expect(1 + 1).toBe(2);

});

});
```

works fine, but for some reason I keep getting this error when I try to follow the rest of the tutorial.

```
Component: Root Component
✖ initialises with a root page of LoginPage
  Firefox 45.0.0 (Linux 0.0.0)
TypeError: win is undefined in src/test.ts (line 937)
```

My src/test.ts is the same as the tutorial and it doesn't have any win in it. My app.spec.ts is this

```
import { TestBed, ComponentFixture, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { UserData } from '../providers/user-data';
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';

let comp: MyApp;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyApp>;

describe('Component: Root Component', () => {

beforeEach(async(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({

        declarations: [MyApp],

        providers: [
            StatusBar,
            SplashScreen,
            UserData,
            Platform
        ],

        imports: [
            IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
        ]

    }).compileComponents();

}));

beforeEach(() => {

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyApp);
    comp    = fixture.componentInstance;

});

afterEach(() => {
    fixture.destroy();
    comp = null;
});

it('initialises with a root page of LoginPage', () => {
    expect(comp['rootPage']).toBe(LoginPage);
});

});
```

And my app.component.ts is this

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { MenuSidePage } from '../pages/menu-side/menu-side';
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';
import { UserData } from '../providers/user-data';


@Component({
  template: `<ion-nav #nav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>`
})
export class MyApp {

  rootPage: any;

  constructor(
    public platform: Platform,
    public statusBar: StatusBar,
    public splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private userData: UserData,
  ) {
    platform
      .ready()
      .then(() => {
        //First - check if user is logged
        if(this.userData.currentUser) { 
          this.rootPage = MenuSidePage;
        } else {
          this.rootPage = LoginPage;
        }
        statusBar.styleDefault();
        splashScreen.hide();

    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have yet the solution, but you shouldn't use `compileComponents()` 'cause you are using a `template` and not a `templateUrl` like said in this [tutorial](https://www.joshmorony.com/introduction-to-testing-ionic-2-applications-with-testbed/) :

"*We need to use compileComponents when we need to asynchronously compile a component, such as one that has an external template (one that is loaded through templateUrl and isn’t inlined with template). This is why the beforeEach block that this code runs in uses an async parameter – it sets up an asynchronous test zone for the compileComponents to run inside.*"

Hope it's a kind of helping :)

Answer (score 0):

The `win()` function come from the `Plaftorm`, you have to mock it as follow :

```javascript
export class PlatformMock {
  public ready(): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      resolve('READY');
    });
  }

  public getQueryParam() {
    return true;
  }

  public registerBackButtonAction(fn: Function, priority?: number): Function {
    return (() => true);
  }

  public hasFocus(ele: HTMLElement): boolean {
    return true;
  }

  public doc(): HTMLDocument {
    return document;
  }

  public is(): boolean {
    return true;
  }

  public getElementComputedStyle(container: any): any {
    return {
      paddingLeft: '10',
      paddingTop: '10',
      paddingRight: '10',
      paddingBottom: '10',
    };
  }

  public onResize(callback: any) {
    return callback;
  }

  public registerListener(ele: any, eventName: string, callback: any): Function {
    return (() => true);
  }

  public win(): Window {
    return window;
  }

  public raf(callback: any): number {
    return 1;
  }

  public timeout(callback: any, timer: number): any {
    return setTimeout(callback, timer);
  }

  public cancelTimeout(id: any) {
    // do nothing
  }

  public getActiveElement(): any {
    return document['activeElement'];
  }
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-unit-testing-example/blob/master/test-config/mocks-ionic.ts) is the link to see a project for real integration of this mock class.

Hope it helps :)